# I can't find the location of jdk for Java 7 and 8

Tags: macos, java

I have 3 different versions (jdk) of Java installed: 6, 7 and 8. In

`bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
setjdk() {
  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1)
}
```

However, at

```
$ ls /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
1.6.0.jdk
```

I see only one version. Where are the 2 other ones? What's the location of their jdks?

Answer (score 11):

You can see the install locations of the recognized JDKs by using `java_home`'s "-V" option:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    1.8.0_31, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_55, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You see newer JDKs are under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. I think it was moved out of "System" after Apple stopped developing the OSK JDK themselves and Oracle took over.

Also see `/usr/libexec/java_home --help` for more options.

Answer (score 2):

In contrary to the Apple provided Java6 which will be installed to `/System/Library/Java` and `/System/Library/Frameworks`, Oracle's Java7 and Java8 are located at `/Library/Java/` in several subfolders.